# How do I unlock a database?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I want to try to run a python script from a samba folder connected to the server. I want my python script from the raspberry pi to write in a temporary database that i will connect with the sql server . But when i try to writhe in the .db it s saying that the database is locked.

```
import sqlite3
def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('//srv/public/fisiere/database/Numaratoare.db',timeout=10)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pontaj (Operator Varchar(25),Loc_munca Varchar(25),Comanada Varchar(25),Stare Varchar(25), Data Varchar(25), Ora Varchar(25), Bucati int)")
    c.close()
    conn.close()

def data_entry(operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('//srv/public/fisiere/database/Numaratoare.db',timeout=10)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Pontaj VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()


def inseraredate(operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati):
    create_table()
    data_entry(operator,loc_munca,comanda,stare,data,ora,bucati)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maintest.py", line 2, in <module>
    inseraredate('test2','la2','curut2','da2','mere2','ma2',101)
  File "/srv/public/functii/baza_date/bazadate.py", line 21, in inseraredate
    create_table()
  File "/srv/public/functii/baza_date/bazadate.py", line 7, in create_table
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pontaj (Operator Varchar(25),Loc_munca Varchar(25),Comanada Varchar(25),Stare Varchar(25), Data Varchar(25), Ora Varchar(25), Bucati int)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite actually [advises *against*](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) using databases on shared network filesystems:

> SQLite uses POSIX advisory locks to implement locking on Unix. On Windows it uses the LockFile(), LockFileEx(), and UnlockFile() system calls. SQLite assumes that these system calls all work as advertised. If that is not the case, then database corruption can result. One should note that POSIX advisory locking is known to be buggy or even unimplemented on many NFS implementations (including recent versions of Mac OS X) **and that there are reports of locking problems for network filesystems under Windows. Your best defense is to not use SQLite for files on a network filesystem.**

I have noticed problems with files remaining locked on ms-windows network filesystems as well. It does seem that such spurious locks are being cleaned out after a while; usually they're gone the next day.

If your program on the raspberry pi is the only one actually changing the data, you could maybe store the database locally and copy it to the network drive. If that copy operation fails then at least you have a local version.

If you really need a database that can be reliably updated from different machines, you're probably better off using a proper database server. This is not what SQLite is made for ([link](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)):

> SQLite strives to provide local data storage for individual applications and devices. SQLite does not compete with client/server databases.